UsageStatsManager doesn't retrieve correct data
I am trying to get the usage data for current week by using UsageStatsManager API. But am unable to retrieve correct data. maybe my implementation is wrong. It retrieves wrong data for past days and also retrieves data for days that haven't come yet. Like if it's Tuesday it retrieves wrong data for Monday and Tuesday then retrieves data for rest of the week which is obviously wrong.
suspend fun getWeeklyUsage(): WeeklyUsage = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val pm: PackageManager = context.packageManager
    var weeklyUsage = WeeklyUsage(
        weekScreenTime = 0,
        weekDuration = "",
        dailyUsages = emptyList(),
    )

    try {
        val usageStatsManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
        val dailyUsages: MutableList<DailyUsage> = mutableListOf()
        var usedAppsList: MutableList<AppUsage> = mutableListOf()

        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1)
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.firstDayOfWeek)

        var startTime = calendar.timeInMillis
        val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault())

        Log.e("Usage Stats", "Start time: ${formatMillisTime(startTime)}, End time: ${formatMillisTime(endTime)}")

        for (day in 0 until 7) {
            val usageStatsList = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(
                UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,
                startTime,
                endTime,
            )

            for (usageStats in usageStatsList) {
                val packageName = usageStats.packageName
                val totalScreenTime = usageStats.totalTimeInForeground

                if (totalScreenTime > 0) {
                    val screenTimeDuration = getDuration(totalScreenTime)
                    val app = try {
                        val packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)
                        val appName = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString()
                        val appIcon = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm)
                        App(
                            packageName = packageName,
                            name = appName,
                            icon = appIcon,
                        )
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Log.e("Screen Usage Repository", "Error: ${e.message}")
                        App(
                            packageName = packageName,
                            name = "",
                        )
                    }

                    val appUsage = AppUsage(
                        app = app,
                        appDuration = screenTimeDuration,
                        appScreenTime = totalScreenTime,
                    )
                    usedAppsList.add(appUsage)
                }
            }

            val date = dateFormat.format(Date(startTime))
            val dayScreenTime = usedAppsList.sumOf(AppUsage::appScreenTime)
            val dayDuration = getDuration(dayScreenTime)
            usedAppsList = usedAppsList.sortedByDescending(AppUsage::appScreenTime).toMutableList()

            val dailyUsage = DailyUsage(
                date = date,
                dayScreenTime = dayScreenTime,
                dayDuration = dayDuration,
                mostUsedApps = usedAppsList,
            )

            dailyUsages.add(dailyUsage)
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)
            startTime = calendar.timeInMillis
        }

        val weekScreenTime = dailyUsages.sumOf(DailyUsage::dayScreenTime)

        val screenTimeDuration = getDuration(weekScreenTime)
        weeklyUsage = WeeklyUsage(
            weekScreenTime = weekScreenTime,
            weekDuration = screenTimeDuration,
            dailyUsages = dailyUsages,
        )
        Log.e("Screen Usage", "Total Screen Usage ${weeklyUsage.weekDuration}")
        weeklyUsage.dailyUsages.forEach { dailyUsage ->
            Log.e("Screen Usage", "Date: ${dailyUsage.date}, Screen Time: ${dailyUsage.dayDuration}")
            dailyUsage.mostUsedApps.forEach {
                Log.e("Screen Usage", "App: ${it.app.name}, Screen Time: ${it.appDuration}")
            }
        }

        weeklyUsage
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Screen Usage Repository", "Error: ${e.message}")
        weeklyUsage
    }
}

data class App(val packageName: String?, val name: String, val icon: Drawable? = null)
data class AppUsage(val app: App, val appDuration: String, val appScreenTime: Long)
data class DailyUsage(val date: String, val dayScreenTime: Long, val dayDuration: String, val mostUsedApps: MutableList<AppUsage>)
data class WeeklyUsage(val weekScreenTime: Long, val weekDuration: String, val dailyUsages: List<DailyUsage>)

